# Simple JQuery selector working, vanilla js isn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

This is not a duplicate of the querySelectorAll as it is not working for querySelector as well

I have the following code in my js file. The JQuery is working, the vanilla js is not, I'd love to know why! Thanks for any help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.chartContainer').text('bar-1'); //works
document.querySelectorAll('.chartContainer').innerHTML[0] = 'bar-2'; //doesn't work
document.querySelector('.chartContainer').innerHTML = 'bar-3'; //doesn't work
```

output (from chrome inspector):

```
<div class="chartWrapper"><div class="chartContainer">bar-1</div></div>
```

I am using Jade as my template engine, here is the code I use:

```
.chartWrapper
      .chartContainer foo
```

Comment: Show us the part of the html file you're trying to manipulate.

Comment: Do you have 1 or multiple `'.chartContainer'`?

Comment: I tried both querySelector and querySelectorAll. I used querySelectorAll in the example, but the result is the same for either.

Comment: Here's your sollution:

      `window.onload=function(){
document.querySelectorAll('.chartContainer')[0].innerHTML = 'bar-2';
      }`

What you needed was to make sure the code is executed only when the div is rendered. This worked on my computer, I hope it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you have only 1 or multiple elements with `chartContainer` class, the `querySelectorAll` function returns a list/ an array of elements. So you should access to the one you want to change with an index operator `[]`

This will be a simple fix:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.chartContainer')[0].innerHTML = 'bar-2';
```

```html
<div class="chartWrapper"><div class="chartContainer">bar-1</div></div>
```

Comment: thank you for looking at this, I eagerly tried it, but it is not working as well:

Comment: then we will need to see the HTML you're working with

Comment: @RonI Are you sure your code is running after the DOM is loaded?

Comment: @RonI It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/c5z98nxr/

Comment: @Barmar - I use $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: @Barmar - thanks, yes I believe this must have something to do with using Jade templates